# Does Xamarin(.Forms) fit my project?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am not quite sure about the best way to handle my project. I need an app for Android and iOS (maybe also Windows Phone later), that's why I thought about Xamarin. Basically, the app has to send some http request, gets data back and shows the data in a nice UI (Charts, ...), so the main part would probably be the UI.

I have some good knowledge in "normal" Android developing with Android Studio. I'd normally search for some gradle plugins (e.g. MPAndroidChart), load them and use them.

So here is my question:

- Should I use Xamarin (Portable), Xamarin (Shared), Xamarin.Forms (Portable) or Xamarin.Forms (Shared)?
- How would you implement this project? Is Xamarin.Forms powerful enough to display Charts and nice UI-Elements?
- I already did some stuff with Xamarin.Forms (mainly for Android) and it seems very difficult to design the UI. I cannot find an element for an Actionbar / Toolbar, ...
- Is it better to not use Xamarin.Forms, and instead writing device specific UI and only "call" methods from the C# Project (The top "project" in the solution, the one without an ".Droid" or ".iOS" extension)
- Are there any additional things I have to keep in mind for my project?

I hope that you guys have some answers for my questions!

Cheers,
DDerTyp

Edit: Dear Stackoverflow-Team, I know that the answers to this question are mostly opinion based. I also know that there are various ways to answer the question. But I hope that you'll not close this question, because it can be a good start for new (Xamarin-)developers. And Stackoverflow is a plotform for both, new and experienced devs. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions first:

- Should I use Xamarin (Portable), Xamarin (Shared), Xamarin.Forms
  (Portable) or Xamarin.Forms (Shared)?

  A: Portable (PCL) is the way to go.
- How would you implement this project? Is Xamarin.Forms powerful
  enough to display Charts and nice UI-Elements?

  A: There's no built-in chart control in Xamarin Forms. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/views/ for a list of built-in controls.
   Also check https://components.xamarin.com/ for more. Additionally, you can always use renderers to bring any native control or native library. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/
- I already did some stuff with Xamarin.Forms (mainly for Android) and
  it seems very difficult to design the UI. I cannot find an element
  for an Actionbar / Toolbar, ...

  A: Being a cross platform framework, Xamarin Forms tries to bring and unify most common features and patterns in a single API. Therefore, you don't get direct access to specific native features, but you can always try to do this by using renderers. Renderers is a key feature to master in Xamarin Forms.
- Is it better to not use Xamarin.Forms, and instead writing device
  specific UI and only "call" methods from the C# Project (The top
  "project" in the solution, the one without an ".Droid" or ".iOS"
  extension)

  A: It depends on how you want the UI on each platform to look like. If the UI is pretty simple and looks same way across different platforms, you can use Xamarin Forms. I can't really tell without seeing the UI.
- Are there any additional things I have to keep in mind for my
  project?

  A: It might sound boring, but after some time I'd suggest you try understand how Xamarin Forms really works. Spend some time looking at Xamarin Forms source code: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms. For this, see http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/build-xamarin-forms-from-source

In case you haven't heard about it already, there's a Xamrin Forms book written by (famous) Charles Petzold: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the insight! I'd like to point out that your links in your answer for my second question the key for getting started. Especially the custom renderer sounds very interesting, but I didnt found much about it in the "official" "tutorials / guides"! :)

Comment: updated with links to the Xamarin Forms book